# What do the values in model.predict() mean?

Tags: machine-learning, conv-neural-network

I ran a CNN for a digit recognizer I found online and when I tried testing the trained model it on a single image my result was this:

```
[[1.4540684e-13 5.0518111e-11 1.5008972e-14 3.2845630e-05 2.6759880e-16
  9.9996710e-01 2.3198607e-10 6.3636325e-14 9.3972552e-10 1.5128480e-10]]
```

Can anyone explain what these values mean or how I should correspond them to my answer?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It depends on how the creator of the CNN model designed it but for the outputs you have, they are likely softmax probabilities associated with each of the 10 classes/digits. Since the 6th value (9.9996710e-01) is nearly equal to 1, the network is indicating that it is highly likely that the input corresponds to the 6th class (which would likely be the digit "5" or "6", depending on whether the classes are counted starting from "0" or "1").

Comment: Thanks! I understand now. I realized I could also call model.predict_classes() to get my answer.